# Data Explorer: Suggested Edits: Group by Review Types per User

Tags: support, data-explorer

Using the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer for Stack Overflow](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/), I’m looking for aggregated counts of review tasks (suggested edits) per user, but I’ve lost track of the tables involved (`ReviewTaskResults`, `SuggestedEditVotes`, etc.). I can’t imagine the base query is that hard to compose.

How to get all completed approved/rejected/improved edit suggestion reviews a user has done?

Comment: None of the tables around reviewtasks contain the user who performed the reviewtask so you can't answer this question. You'll need to scrape the review history.

Comment: @rene: That's a setback. I could rephrase the question: Where does the data come from to display *“Community has approved 297542 edit suggestions and rejected 155813 edit suggestions and improved 1209 edit suggestions”*?

Answer (score 1):

I think [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/525488/suggested-reviews-you-have-done-and-their-end-result) is what you are after:

```
DECLARE @UserId int = ##UserId##
    
select top 10
       rtk.Id [Review Id]
,      sed.Id [Suggested Edit Link]
,      sed.PostId [Post Link]
,      rtt.Name [Review End Result]
,      vte.Name [Your Vote]
from   ReviewTaskResults rtr
join   ReviewTaskResultTypes rtt
on     rtr.ReviewTaskResultTypeId = rtt.Id
join   ReviewTasks rtk
on     rtr.ReviewTaskId = rtk.Id
join   SuggestedEdits sed
on     sed.Id = rtk.SuggestedEditId
join   SuggestedEditVotes sev
on     sev.SuggestedEditId = sed.Id
join   VoteTypes vte
on     sev.VoteTypeId = vte.Id
where  sev.UserId = @UserId
```

It gets all suggested edits votes of you and joins that with the end result of the review task and your vote on it.

I would suggest to try this query on a low-traffic site since it will blow up the database using SO.

Comment: *blowing up stuff ...*