# Data Explorer: How to query for “Reviewer Stats” data?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits, data-explorer

Along [any suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/235898), there’s “Reviewer Stats” on all involved reviewers, like this one:

> <sub>Community has approved 297542 edit suggestions and rejected 155813 edit suggestions and improved 1209 edit suggestions.</sub>

What’s the query for this data on completed review tasks? Or, more precisely, how to get those *three* aggregate values for *each* reviewer given a *single* edit suggestion?

Actually, I’m not interested in data on a *particular* suggestion:

It’s about the **Approval-Rejection-Improvement ratio** among *all* review users. Questions be like:

1. Who rejected the most?
2. Whose ratio between approval and rejection is least/most balanced?
3. What users are the top improvers relative to their other review types?
4. Which reviewers tend to be the most discerning/benevolent?

I hope to have put it into right words this time. Also, I’m confident at this point that I can compose a suitable query myself as soon as I know how the reviewer stats are queried for.

---

<sup>*Note: Some time ago, I submitted [a similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283516/) in different phrasing.*</sup>

Comment: here is reject/approve: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/626632  I don't know how to get improve.

Comment: Thanks @rene, that’s a good start! Other [people wonder](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289506/) where to find improvements. I, for one, wonder why the query yields 42/95 for my userid, while the interface says 42/147 (reviewer). It’s an ongoing mystery. Thanks again so far!

Comment: SEDE doesn't have the data for deleted questions so that could explain the difference.