# How to query the Data Explorer for reviewer stats

Tags: discussion, review, data-explorer

I've been trying to figure out if it's possible to query the Data Explorer to give me data similar to what you get when you hover over people's names:

> [image: Hover over names in Review queues]

I thought it may be similar to the SuggestedEditsVotes which has `UserID`, however neither ReviewTasks or ReviewTaskResults has `UserID`, I therefore assumed this may not be possible and decided to ask here.

I'm aware of [this related question with a similar title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290888/data-explorer-how-to-query-for-reviewer-stats-data). However that question is asking about Suggested Edits, which I'm also interested in, however I would like it for all the review queues. (Mostly because I'd like to see how many I'm getting compared to other frequent reviewers)

Comment: Let me know if this isn't how I'm meant to ask questions here and I'll try to fix it.

Comment: SEDE is only update weekly so you won't be able to exactly mimic that and until the userid is added to the reviewtasks you won't be able to gather those stats. Scraping the site is your only option  but that comes with great limitations of throttling.

Comment: @rene I was mostly looking for the monthly and weekly ones, but I thought that it likely wouldn't have been possible

Comment: As I can remember, some of the review votes are actually stored as *flags*, despite that their support as *vote* still exists in the db. So check the *flags*. Additional note: the review entity is a diferent thing as the vote/question entity. Thus, what you did in a review, is a different thing, what are your current votes/flags on a post.