# Is it possible to estimate the active reviewer population using the SEDE data?

Tags: discussion, support, review, data-explorer, data-dump

My main site has, I think, a problem with a shrinking reviewer population, and I would like to use the SEDE data to estimate whether this is indeed the case and, if so, how bad it is and how it has evolved over time.

As such, I would like to use the SEDE data to answer specific questions of the form

> How many users completed at least *x* reviews (where 0 < *x* < 20) at least *y* days of the week, each week over the history of the site?

This is the kind of data that *ought* to be public (since reviews are public, even if the question has been deleted ([example](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/close/214616)), though admittedly the listing itself is not easily available below 10k), but I'm struggling with finding data to tie specific users to reviews on the SEDE corpus.

Is this possible at all? If so, using which data? If not, would it be possible to expand the SEDE corpus using public data that will enable this kind of analysis?

Comment: While you have the reviewtasks in SEDE, you don't have the reviewer in the public SEDE. You'll need staff to query this on their internal instance.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291496/how-to-query-the-data-explorer-for-reviewer-stats